# Flutter - how to position the background to the bottom with stack

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, background-image

I'm a beginner at app dev and I'm trying out flutter. I'm currently having a problem with positioning my background on the project that I am currently testing out.I'm following a UI kit that I am trying to copy for the purpose of practicing, but I am having problem with the UI.

I tried using stack but the whole screen is wrapped with its children and not taking up space. it looks like this:

[image: what i tried]

and this is what I wanted to do:

[image: what i want to do]

This is the background that I wanted to put in my app, it is not literally a background or wallpaper because of its size. I just needed this to be placed at the bottom of the screen or background:
[image: background image]

this is the code that I currently have:

```
import 'package:audit_finance_app/constant/theme.dart';
import 'package:audit_finance_app/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:audit_finance_app/screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignInPage> createState() => _SignInPageState();
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  late List<String> inputPass;
  String defaultPass = '1234';

  @override
  void initState() {
    inputPass = [];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
            ),
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        AuditTheme.primaryColor,
                        AuditTheme.secondaryColor,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                leadingWidth: 100,
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: const [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/logo/white_logo.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Audit',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                title: const Text('Sign In'),
                centerTitle: true,
                actions: [
                  Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.sort),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Widgets().sixedBoxHeight(50),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            const CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 35,
                              backgroundImage:
                                  AssetImage('assets/logo/audit_logo.png'),
                            ),
                            Widgets().sixedBoxHeight(10),
                            const Text(
                              'Ledjoric Vermont',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            pinIconTest(inputPass.isNotEmpty
                                ? Colors.black
                                : Colors.grey),
                            pinIconTest(inputPass.length >= 2
                                ? Colors.black
                                : Colors.grey),
                            pinIconTest(inputPass.length >= 3
                                ? Colors.black
                                : Colors.grey),
                            pinIconTest(inputPass.length == 4
                                ? Colors.black
                                : Colors.grey),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  numPad(const Text('1'), () => inputPin('1')),
                                  numPad(const Text('2'), () => inputPin('2')),
                                  numPad(const Text('3'), () => inputPin('3')),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  numPad(const Text('4'), () => inputPin('4')),
                                  numPad(const Text('5'), () => inputPin('5')),
                                  numPad(const Text('6'), () => inputPin('6')),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  numPad(const Text('7'), () => inputPin('7')),
                                  numPad(const Text('8'), () => inputPin('8')),
                                  numPad(const Text('9'), () => inputPin('9')),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                  ),
                                  numPad(const Text('0'), () => inputPin('0')),
                                  numPad(
                                    const Icon(Icons.backspace_sharp),
                                    () => deletePin(),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pinIconTest(Color color) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.circle,
        size: 35,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget numPad(Widget widget, void Function() function) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: function,
        child: widget,
      ),
    );
  }

  void inputPin(String value) {
    setState(() {
      inputPass.length != 4 ? inputPass.add(value) : null;
      inputPass.length == 4 ? checkPass() : null;
    });
    print(inputPass);
  }

  void checkPass() {
    var stringList = inputPass.join('');
    if (stringList == defaultPass) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
    print(stringList);
  }

  void deletePin() {
    setState(() {
      inputPass.isNotEmpty ? inputPass.removeLast() : null;
    });
    print(inputPass);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must set `fit: StackFit.expand` for the `Stack` then instead of using a column for your background you have to use a `Container` with  `width: double.maxFinite, height: double.maxFinite` where inside of it is the background image as you shows by "assets/logo/audit_logo.png"

Comment: For separate context of question you must open a new record. That because of new USERS of SO as is that the purpose of this platform (helping each-other) making questions/answers simply and clearly!!

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj the stack.expand return an error for me

Comment: try `new_gradient_app_bar`. Link: https://pub.dev/packages/new_gradient_app_bar

Comment: Pay attention of this hierarchy :  `child: Scaffold(body: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[BackgroundWidget(), Body(), ToolBar()])))`

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj but I'm using sliver so the actual body is in the `SliverList()`. Where do I put it in my code that I posted in the question?

Comment: Because of that you cannot have the desired result. a Grid/Sliver etc should be considered as rows one above the other, so, the background you've placed is in one of those where doesn't cover all the surface of device screen. You have to change order of widget as I suggest in my comment. That code is one of my fullscreen apps

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj I updated my question with the suggestions you said, can you look at it? I don't know what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the fact you want to place at the bottom that background, however to achieve that you can do it as the code below shows:

```
class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignInPage> createState() => _SignInPageState();
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
            ),
          ),
          //Other child here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: it works! any tips on how can I make the other child which is in the `SliverChildListDelegate` fullscreen?

Comment: Glad to hear that :).  Related to " how can I make the other child fullscreen"? You cannot as it is a grid. Even you make a row of the screen dimensions you can lose the effect on scroll movement of that grid. Fullscreen Widget goes inside a Stack. A stack can be considered as a container where widgets are as layers one above of other in other side Grids, lists containers etc have an inline placement of their childs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example below for the status bar. I don't know about the real problem.
You can try using this way for gradient color

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle systemUiOverlayStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  statusBarGradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  ),
);
```

Comment: I already have that but it does not llet me put gradient color. How do I use gradient color in there?

Comment: it says to me, there is no named parameter "statusBarGradient".

Comment: but the `statusBarColor: Colors.transparent` solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your image in a [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) Widget.

```
Positioned(bottom: 0.0,
           child: const SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
     ),
 ),
```

Or you can use the [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/alignment.html) property of the Stack to stick everything onto the bottom. I'm not sure this is exactly what you want though.

```
body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
        ),
      ),
```